# Set a value to a variable based on the results of a query (in PL/pgSQL style)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

What I need to do is set a value to a variable using the `EXECUTING` query.

In pure SQL style, I could do something like the following:

```
// here declaring function and etc...
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;

EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t' INTO cnt;
```

How to achieve the same functionality in the form of a PL/pgSQL function? What is the correct syntax for the following pseudo-code? (The following is obviously the wrong syntax)

```
cnt :=  EXECUTE ( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t' )   ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "plpgsql style". The syntax you showed is perfectly OK, as shown in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: In "plpgsql style" I mean `variable :=`, but as see, this syntax is not for working dynamic commands. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
cnt := COUNT(*) FROM t;
```

Answer (score 10):

you can use SELECT INTO

```
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
SELECT INTO cnt count(*) FROM t;
```

Comment: It's select count(*) into cnt I believe

Comment: how to assign multiple variables in select?